# what is app LICENSE KEY for?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I've start reading about implementing in-app billing in my android app , the documentation says

> **Protect your Google Play public key**
>
> To keep your public key safe from malicious users and hackers, do not
>   embed it in any code as a literal string. Instead, construct the
>   string at runtime from pieces or use bit manipulation (for example,
>   XOR with some other string) to hide the actual key. The key itself is
>   not secret information, but you do not want to make it easy for a
>   hacker or malicious user to replace the public key with another key.

so how dangerous it is if the someone else knows the public key , what he can do with it ?

Comment: Updated the answer. Is that what you want ? Please mark as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

### What can be done with the secret keys?

Per the report, Android applications contained thousands of leaked secret authentication keys, which in turn can be used by malicious users to gain unauthorized access to server resources through Amazon Web Services and compromise user accounts on Facebook.

Reference:

https://www.quora.com/How-worried-should-Android-users-be-about-the-secret-keys-found-in-Google-Play

Comment: ok , if I a hacker get the key what he can do with it ? can he stall my money from merchant account or something ?

Comment: @ITDevelopers haver you read the article ? I think the article will answer this question. I don't think the hacker will be able to get you money or smth like that. But you never know.

Answer (score 0):

If your public key is hard-coded and un-obfuscated in the app, an attacker may be able to replace it with his own public key and enable any client-side validation to return true.

If an attacker replaces your public key with one that he knows the private key for, he could produce purchase receipts without ever contacting the server and your app will think they are real.